# How to get lines and nodes around the confluence point in a network system (line shapefile)?

Tags: python, shapefile, point, line, network

I got a network line shapefile and the figure below was part of it. I want to do task around confluence point, so I took photo around confluence point as figure below.

[image]

I want to get **line segments (unique geometry of line)** and **nodes (coordinates of node)** around every confluence point in the shapefile, as the schematic figure below (closer look of figure above).

[image]

Now I use QGIS and manually select those segments and store node coordinates (via `extract node`) in CSV files. Because the network is too complicated and has many confluences, I want to do this in a much more efficient way.

***The Idea***
I think that maybe I could **scan** the whole network to find every confluence by finding node with more than 2 intersecting lines, and get set of line segments (in figure above, `lines = line1, line2, line3`) and nodes on the other side of the segment. (in the figure above, `nodes = node1, node2, node3`) (**To be more specific**, **segment** here means the line with detail in every row of attribute table of this line shapefile, not the little segment showed as I start editting.) Each confluence has its specific set, and in the case above, the set is:

```
geom of line1, coordinates of node1
geom of line2, coordinates of node2
geom of line3, coordinates of node3
```

How can I get the line segment and its node around the confluence point (auto-determine-and-find) in a network-like line shapefile?

And as I described in the paragraph above, because line shapefile I got is complicated, there could be many confluence points, thus I want found lines and nodes could be grouped in the same set based on the confluence points which they intersected.

I don't know if my idea works and what function or tool could help me to achieve my goal. I want to achieve this via open-sources, and ultimately write a integrated python function to get those lines and nodes.

Comment: What is your question?  You seem to be describing what you want to do but not what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: I made a conclusion of question in the last paragraph in the post. I think the core question is that could I get line segment and its node around the confluence point (auto-determine-and-find) in a network-like line shapefile?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make what you are asking clear.  Potential answerers do not always have time to read the comments when deciding which question to answer.

Comment: Your question was still a bit buried so I edited to try and make it more obvious.  I think questions here need to always have one and one only clear question, rather than starting to talk about core (and potentially non-core or sub) questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You work here with a Graph ([Graph Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)) and your confluence point is simply a node with a degree (number of edges adjacent to that node) > 2.

As you mentioned a Python tag, a solution in Python with [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) (for reading the shapefile) and [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) (Graph Theory)

The Polylines

[image]

Open the shapefile and convert all the segments of the Polylines in egdes of a Graph

```
import fiona
import networkx as nx
import itertools # for extracting all the line segments
# creation of an undirected Graph
G = nx.Graph()
for line in fiona.open("lines.shp"):
   # convert the line segments to Graph edges
   for seg_start, seg_end in itertools.izip(line['geometry']['coordinates'],line['geometry']['coordinates'][1:]):
       G.add_edge(seg_start, seg_end)
```

The Graph with Nodes(x) and edges

[image]

Now, in [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/), the degrees of a node are obtained by `degree` (I use [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) here but you can save the resulting shapefiles with Fiona and even Networkx)

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
for node in G.nodes_iter():
    if G.degree(node) > 2:
        print Point(node) #the nodes
        for edge in G.edges(node):
            print LineString(edge) # the edges (>2)
```

Result

[image]

You can translate easily the Fiona solution in PyQGIS.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I edited my post to make my question clearer.

Comment: For python 3 users, changed `nodes_iter()` to `nodes()` and change `itertools_izip()` to `zip()`