# Resolving non-keyword arg after keyword arg error in Python script?

Tags: python, grass-gis, fiona

I tried the following script to get drainage basin of specific points:

```
import sys, os
import fiona
import networkx as nx
import itertools
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import numpy

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['GISBASE'], 'etc', 'python'))
import grass.script as g
print 'import GRASS ok'
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE']
gisdb = 'C:\Users\Heinz\Documents\grassdata'
location = 'nl'
mapset = 'nl'                        
gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)

H = nx.Graph()
for line in fiona.open('tc_line.shp'):
    for seg_start, seg_end in itertools.izip(line['geometry']['coordinates'],line['geometry']['coordinates'][1:]):
        H.add_edge(seg_start, seg_end)

edge_node = []
i = 1
for node in H.nodes_iter():
    if H.degree(node) > 2:
        for edge in H.edges(node):
            print edge
            g.run_command('r.water.outlet', overwrite = True, input = 'dra', basin = 'netx' + str(i), coordinates = edge[1][0], edge[1][1])
```

And the script ran fine until I add `g.run_command('r.water.outlet', overwrite = True, input = 'dra', basin = 'netx' + str(i), coordinates = edge[1][0], edge[1][1])`, and the error showed up:

```
File "C:\Users\Heinz\Desktop\netx_test.py", line 29
g.run_command('r.water.outlet', overwrite = True, input = 'dra', basin = 'netx' + str(i), coordinates = edge[1][0], edge[1][1])
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

So I am wondering that could Fiona work with GRASSGIS? And I want to know how to solve this problem.

I am working under Win10 64bits with python 2.7.12, Fiona 1.7.0, networkx 1.11 and GRASS GIS 7.0.5 installed via OSGeo4W pacakge.

Comment: It is not a problem of Fiona here but a problem of NetworkX  because you  work with edges ([How to get lines and nodes around the confluence point in a network system (line shapefile)?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/215880/2581)). and errors in your script (comment of Luke)

Comment: I tried @Luke's comment and it works, thank you both for the advice! Should I close the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory. You have a non keyword argument after your keyword arguments.

`coordinates = edge[1][0]` is being interpreted as the entire (keyword) argument and `edge[1][1]` as a separate (non-keyword) argument.

Try the following instead:

```
g.run_command('r.water.outlet', overwrite = True, input = 'dra', basin = 'netx' + str(i), coordinates = (edge[1][0], edge[1][1]))
```